# Blending Problem Without Percents and Varying Units of Measure

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm attempting to write a blending/production planning type linear program but am struggling due to the complexity of the manufacturing process.

I am formulating the problem as such:

Objective: Maximize Profit = z = (Sum of component qty in each product) * Profit/Unit of product

D.V.'s:
Xij = units of components (ingredients) i in product j

i = set of components (i = 1,2,...n)
j = set of products (j = 1,2,...n)

Constraints:

Recipe Constraint: Component Requirement <= (Qty of Component in Product j) / (Total Qty of Product j)

Inventory Constraint: Sum of component qty used in each product <= total inventory for each component

---

The issue I'm having is with the units of measure in the recipes of each product. Unlike a classic blending problem, the units of measure vary and I do not have conversion factors to align them all to the same unit as the finished product.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, I have unit factor requirements, so 0.0116 pounds of C1 yields 1 Square Yard of finished good and so on. Unfortunately, the component quantities xij would not be additive because the units differ in the objective function and I would have a similar issue in the recipe constraint.

Has anyone found a workaround for an issue like this?

Comment: "... so 0.0116 pounds of C1 yields 1 Square Yard of finished good ..." Are you sure about this? I would interpret the table to say that one square yard of the product contains 0.0116 pounds of C1.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That is correct.

Comment: You wrote your recipe constraint as an inequality. Is there any reason why it would not be an equality? In other words, is there any incentive to putting more of some component in a product than the minimum amount required?

Comment: Every constraint is for a component i. I don't see any addition of $x_{i,j}$ across component i. As for objective there's should be dollar amount for units of component used in total units of products.